# vertical list of css buttons

Tags: html, css

I want to have a list of vertical buttons, above each other of the same size not depending on what is their text.

this is what I have tried so far:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" href="http://localhost:11555/category" role="button">category</a>
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" href="http://localhost:11555/Team" role="button">Teams</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" href="http://localhost:11555/tournament" role="button">Tournaments</a>
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" href="http://localhost:11555/game" role="button">Games</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" href="http://localhost:11555/News" role="button">News</a>
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" href="http://localhost:11555/Ads" role="button">ADS</a>
```

using bootstrap, but the size of the button is very large, the width im talking about, it says "those that span the full width of a parent" I don't understand what does that mean

Comment: Here seems to align vertical correct [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nmme0aj7/)

Comment: I know it's aligning vertical I have a problem with the size of the buttons how can I change their sizes?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nmme0aj7/4/)

Comment: The answer marked as correct is actually wrong. It will work with inline styles but why use inline when you are following a framework.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the buttons are to width you should put them in a container and adjust the size of the container. If the buttons are to high you can use `btn-sm` instead of `btn-lg`:

```
<div id="buttonContainer" style="width:200px; <!--Change this for more or less width!-->">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" href="http://localhost:11555/category" role="button">category</a>
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" href="http://localhost:11555/Team" role="button">Teams</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" href="http://localhost:11555/tournament" role="button">Tournaments</a>
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" href="http://localhost:11555/game" role="button">Games</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" href="http://localhost:11555/News" role="button">News</a>
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" href="http://localhost:11555/Ads" role="button">ADS</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the class "btn-lg" for you  tags. replace it with "btn-sm" for small buttons or just remove that class for normal size.

if you want the buttons column width to fit wrap the button in a div tag and apply a bootstrap column class to that div.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="col-md-2">
      .....you buttons here
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-10">
      .... some other content
   </div>
<div>
```